# nan score for self-created process

Tags: brightway

I am currently working with self-created processes in Brightway2 and I get nan scores when I try to run LCA. The processes are composed of ecoinvent 3.6 activities. Each ecoinvent activity has a correct score but when running the global process, the right score is not calculated. After looking into the lca code, it seems the linear solver for the technosphere matrix and the demand array returns an array full of nan. Any ideas to fix this ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing `NaN` values, you aren't presenting a linear system that can be solved. My guess is that you are missing a production exchange for your self-created process. As we don't have details, we can't really see how this was created, but if it missing a production exchange (the value commonly given on the diagonal), the technosphere matrix will be singular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to work with the production exchanges added. What's strange is that the calculation was running fine on another project that did not have production exchanges for the self-created processes...

Comment: Not sure why things would be inconsistent - that's not great - but it could be a change somewhere in whether bw2data would automatically add production exchanges. This is a fine line, as adding them automatically helps some while frustrating others who don't want or need production exchanges at all...